# Jquery: Prepend href to a dynamic href

Tags: jquery, dynamic, href, prepend

I have a dynamic href that does not have a class or id and I need to accomplish 2 things.  First I need to be able to identify that the href is qualify.

Something along the lines of if

```
$("a[href*='somestring']")
```

do this:

captures whole href tag and prepends to it.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "identify that the href is qualify."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values) method with a function argument to modify the attribute instead of replacing it:

```
$('a').attr('href',function(i,v) { // you should use a more specific selector
    return "http://www.google.com?search=" + v;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fXUNE/

Comment: Yours is better than mine, I never knew you could do this. TIL!

Comment: That works for second part but first I need to be able to match the href.  So let's say I only want it to work with hrefs that have the string "somestring" in it (http://www.blahblah.com/somestring/help).  I imagine an if/else statement would work?

Comment: Just use a more specific selector. You were already on the right track with the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).